# Is it possible to have wall's bricks to different width?

Tags: mesh

I am wondering is there a possibility (an easy) way to do this? That the bricks stick from the wall with different widths?

Comment: please add more information to your question. How are you generating the bricks?

Comment: I don't yet know. I have the walls ready, but there is no bricks in them. Is there a quick way to add them through some modifier? I mean By subdividing?

Comment: please [edit] your question and describe in detail what you want to accomplish

Comment: I want to accomplish a wall which has Stones that are like this: https://www.google.fi/search?q=wall+brick&biw=1829&bih=1031&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid4ovswYLOAhVIfywKHWNhBI0Q_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=wall+brick+ancient&imgrc=cwFHm2U2gpTSOM%3A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, yet not very customizable, way is to use the displacement modifier.

To start, create a plane for the wall.
[image]

Next, press `w` on the keyboard and select subdivide and change the number of cuts to 10.

[image]

This will help hold the shape of the plane when we add a Multires modifier.
Add a multires modifier now.
[image]

Go ahead and subdivide it about 4 times.  The more subdivisions, the more detailed the wall will be.

Now add a displacement modifier and edit the texture by clicking the Show Texture in Texture Tab button.

[image]

It is the Rightmost button.

In the texture tab, change the texture type to image or movie.  Now you need to upload a displacement map.  A displacement map is simply a black and white image. I just got one off google by searching "bricks displacement map".

Once you upload the image you will need to adjust the strength of the displacement modifier.

[image]
I changed mine to about 0.05
Here is my end result:
[image]

That should do it!  I know there are probably better ways to do it, but this way works well if you are going for realism.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, could you please mark it as Best Answer?  You do that my clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  Thanks!